# Call asyncio Future in scope

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I'm trying to get the progession of my asyncIO Futures. For some reason, I can't get value updates inside any other scope.

For example:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time
import asyncio
import random

def get_progress(futures):
    return sum([f.done() for f in futures])

def long_task(t):
    time.sleep(1.5)
    return t

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
futures_ = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, long_task, i) for i in inputs]

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(get_progress(futures_))
```

It prints only `0`. However, if I run this inside a terminal and call `get_progress(futures_)` it prints 7 as expected.

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Asyncio futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) returned by [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) are designed to run in the asyncio event loop and are distinct from [concurrent ones](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future). The correct asyncio code would look like this:

```
async def track_progress():
    for i in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(get_progress(futures_))

loop.run_until_complete(track_progress())
```

It prints 0 4 4 7 7.

Note that you don't need asyncio and `run_in_executor` if you just want to run stuff in threads - `concurrent.futures` is perfectly capable of handling that on its own. For example:

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
futures_ = [executor.submit(long_task, i) for i in inputs]
```

Since [`executor.submit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) real concurrent futures, `futures_` contains them as well. With this modification your original `for` loop that tracks their progress will work just fine and also print 0 4 4 7 7.

Comment: Thank you for this clear example. I was not aware of `executor.submit`, thanks for the tip!